# How to extract tar archive from stdin?

Tags: pipe, stdin, tar, pipeline

I have a large tar file I `split`. Is it possible to `cat` and untar the file using pipeline.

Something like:

```
cat largefile.tgz.aa largefile.tgz.ab | tar -xz
```

instead of:

```
cat largefile.tgz.aa largfile.tgz.ab > largefile.tgz
tar -xzf largefile.tgz
```

I have been looking around and I can't find the answer. I wanted to see if it was possible.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use `-` as the input file:

```
cat largefile.tgz.aa largefile.tgz.ab | tar zxf -
```

Make sure you cat them in the same order they were split.

If you're using zsh you can use the multios feature and avoid invoking cat:

```
< largefile.tgz.aa < largefile.tgz.ab tar zxf -
```

Or if they are in alphabetical order:

```
<largefile.tgz.* | tar zxf -
```

Comment: Remember that if you have plain uncompressed tar files (rare, but happens), leave off the `z` flag.