# How can we download a specific folder from a gitlab repository using curl or wget?

Tags: curl, directory, gitlab, wget, gitlab-api

I know how to download a file from a gitlab repo and I didn't find anything on downloading a directory.
I need to download only a directory.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used curl or wget but you can use [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951) to get the similar thing done.

This should solve your problem. :)

Comment: I had to do it using curl/wget

Answer (score 0):

You could try and combine:

- a [`git archive --remote` approach](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/does-gitlab-support-git-archive-remote/23521/2) which will get the latest files (no history): see [`git archive --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#Documentation/git-archive.txt---remoteltrepogt)
- with [extracting the folder from the tarball](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35315/7490)

That is ([extracting a  tar archive from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526570/6309)):

```
git archive --remote git@gitlab.com:<user>/<repo> main | tar -xvf - specificDir
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution to download a specific folder,
to download the complete repository I used following approach:

curl --request GET --header PRIVATE-TOKEN:${GITLAB_TOKEN}  https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/project_id/repository/archive/ | tar -xz -C /tmp/project-name/

Comment: You can download a single directory by specifying the path, I posted an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77110671/2411320. Thanks for sharing nevertheless, +1!

Answer (score 0):

As @VonC edit queue is full, here is the correct command line for git archive:

```sh
git archive --remote git@gitlab.com:<user>/<repo> main | tar -xvf - specificDir
```

- main: is branch name
- specificDir: specific dir to untar, it's optional

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we download a specific folder from a gitlab repository using curl?

Like this:

```
curl --output my_directory_1.tar.xz--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/archive/?path=my_directory_0/my_directory_1/"
```

where in this example I downloaded an archive of the subdirectory named `"my_directory_1"`, from a Gitlab project with a `<project_id>` (e.g. `77`), where the path to the subdirectory was `"my_directory_0/my_directory_1/"` (without the project name, since we have defined the project ID).

Now I can uncompress it like this:

```
tar -xvf my_directory_1.tar.xz
```

Read more in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70172000/2411320).

Answer (score 0):

You can use these git sparse commands:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch release_12.10 --no-checkout 
https://github.com/project/karma.git
cd karma
git sparse-checkout set directory/subdirectory/subsubdirectory
```

This will checkout only subsubdirectory as per my example and nothing else.